# How do I reload browser when a link or checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I reload the web browser when I click on link or checkbox without opening a new blank tab? Currently when I click on the link or checkbox, it reloads the page but open a blank tab too. See code below:

```html
<a type="button" class="styled" onclick="openWindowReload(this)">remove your consent</a> at any time. <br />

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" onclick="openWindowReload(this)">

<script>
  function openWindowReload(link) {
  var href = link.href;
  window.open(href,'_blank');
  document.location.reload(true)
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the script tag. Try this:

```
<a type="button" class="styled" onclick="location.reload();">remove your consent</a> at any time. <br />

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" onclick="location.reload();">
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you want to use the `script`, and just want to know what is wrong with your current code:

Removing `window.open(href,'_blank');` should do the trick. The next line, `document.location.reload(true)` is the part required to reload the page.

Otherwise, @mattias's answer is more compact and works better.

Comment: @mattias Thanks buddy!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback buddy!